# Running Java from CLI works fine, but executing the same from SH won't make Java find the class

Tags: java, linux, sh, centos6, command-line-interface

I am trying to run a Java server on Linux, which works fine when I run it from the CLI.

The following code works if I execute it from the right folder (requires some files, so I can't execute it from another folder at this point):

```
java -classpath "/var/server/dist/*" net.world.WorldServer
```

As soon as I make an SH file with this exact same code in the folder, and I execute it with the following command:

```
./launch_server.sh OR bash launch_server.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class net.world.WorldServer
```

I have been searching Google for people who have a similar problem, but could not find an answer that would help me with it.

The following I have tried did not help;

1. Set CLASSPATH before execution (in the SH file) *[export CLASSPATH="/var/server/dist/*"]*
2. Set CLASSPATH as a server environment variable *[export CLASSPATH="/var/server/dist/*"]*

My Java version:

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

CentOS version:

```
CentOS release 6.4 (Final) [64-Bit]
```

I am executing this all as "root" and I have full access to the server.

If you need more information to solve this, please let me know in a comment, and I will get the information as fast as possible and edit the question.

Thanks in advance! ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running directly on a terminal, `"/var/server/dist/*"` is getting expanded by bash before passing the string to `java`, so it ends up being a valid classpath (`/var/server/dist/some.jar:/var/server/dist/other.jar...` so on).

To make it work inside a shell script you need to build the classpath string, something like

```
classpath=""
for i in `ls /var/server/dist/*jar`
do 
   classpath=$i:$classpath
done

java -classpath $classpath
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks for the answer, this save me a lot of time!